# Insert into CSV file from two tables using Talend

Tags: database, csv, talend

I have two tables `command` and `commandItem`:

```
command: code, date, amount
commandItem: commandCode, price, label
```

I would to get this output in a CSV file:

```
Command1;26-01-2018;100
Command1;9;label1
Command1;81;label2
Command1;10;label3
Command2;26-01-2018;50
Command2;10;label1
Command2;20;label2
Command2;20;label3
```

Can you tell me how to do it using Talend?

Comment: How are the items related to commands ? I'm guessing commandCode = code, but in your example data, they are not the same ?

Comment: Yes, you are right. I just edited my post. @iMezouar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have access to my test database at the moment in order to show you a solution with tables, so I did it with files, but the general idea is the same :

[image]

The idea here is to read your commands table, and for each row, write it to file (in **Append** mode); and before passing to the next row, write (to the **same file**, in **Append** mode) the related rows from items table (you need to replace the part where I read items file + `tFilterRow` by your database input component, containing a filtering condition like so: `WHERE commandCode = (String)globalMap.get("row1.code")` in order to get items for the current command only)

[image]

The settings of both `tFileOutputDelimited` components are **identical** and look like this :

[image]

You need to set "`Custom flush buffer size`" to 1 in order to flush each row immediately to file, otherwise the order of rows won't be garanteed in the output file.

Output:

```
Command1;26-01-2018;100
Command1;9;label1
Command1;81;label2
Command1;10;label3
Command2;26-01-2018;50
Command2;10;label1
Command2;20;label2
Command2;20;label3
```

I bet there are other (better?) ways to achieve this, but it's the first that came to mind.